# Monitoring files entering and leaving the folder(file queue)

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-monitoring

I have a Folder which is assumed to be a file queue, every second many files enter and leave the file queue. I want to write a script which will maintain 2 log files. One will log the name of file and time at which the file entered the file queue, the other will log the name of the file and time at which the file will leave the queue. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think with a batch file you can't reach that goal.

I would prefer a C# console application or a powershell script. In both cases the `FileSystemWatcher` would be the needed class.

- [C# documentation and example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Powershell example](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: You _can_, but you really don't want to; checking the same folder every second will completely lock up your computer.

Comment: @SomethingDark: That's what I meant with *can't reach that goal.*

Comment: I was agreeing with you, and merely expanding upon what you said.

Comment: Can I run a service that will do the logging for me? I was thinking whether I can use Splunk for this

Comment: @ArunKumar: Absolutely. First write a console application (e.g. with C#) and let it do what you want. Afterwards take a look at [how the create a windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) or use a library like [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com).